# In a topological space, every union of sets must also be a set?

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to understand the meaning of topological spaces, without being a mathematician. In particular, the definition via open sets, where the axioms are 1) X (the set of elements) and the empty set are subsets of T; 2) any intersection of subsets in T is also a subset in T; 3) any union of subsets is also a subset in T.

The Union axiom is what throws me. I have a set of elements {A,B,C,D}. Suppose I make each element a member of a subset, so now I have at least {A}, {B}, {C}, and {D}.

Does this then mean the only possible topological space including those subsets, is the power set?

Because I would think that e.g. {AB}, {BC}, {CD}, {ABC}, {BCD} (in addition to the sets already mentioned) would make e.g. a linear space (ordering the elements from A to B). For example.

But according to the axioms, these would not be "topological spaces", correct? Because we do not have the subsets {AC}, {BD}, etc. Then, what is a set of sets like this ({A},{B},{C},{D},{AB},{BC},{CD},{ABC},{BCD},{ABCD})? How can we (or can we) use the concept of 'topological spaces' to distinguish between different ways of ordering the elements in X (as along a line, or in a plane, or etc)?

I seem to be thinking of a different kind of thing, where you have unions only of sets that intersect. What would that be?

Am I fundamentally confused about the difference between "space" and "topological space" (are they not so similar as I thought)?

Thanks!

Comment: Not "any intersection", it should be " finite intersection ".

Comment: (2): Any intersection of _finitely many_ open sets is also an open set. The infinitely many open intervals $(-\tfrac1n,\tfrac1n)\subset\mathbb R$, for $n\in\mathbb N$, intersect only in $\{0\}$ which is not an open set. But (3) is correct.

Comment: Note that $\{A,B\}=\{B,A\}$. There is no sense of ordering.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this then mean the only possible topological space including those subsets, is the power set?

Yes, that's correct. The topology where every singleton belongs to the topology is precisely the power set. A.k.a. the discrete space. Boring. Most spaces we encounter don't have this property.

> How can we (or can we) use the concept of 'topological spaces' to distinguish between different ways of ordering the elements in X (as along a line, or in a plane, or etc)?

Ordering? We can't do that. Topology doesn't care about ordering.

Moreover the concepts of line and plane cannot be defined just in terms of topology. You need more structure than that. Maybe linear spaces, maybe geometry axioms, but not just topology.

> Am I fundamentally confused about the difference between "space" and "topological space" (are they not so similar as I thought)?

"Space" as in $3$-dimensional reality that surrounds us? Yes, these are very different things. Topology captures mostly the idea of "shape" but is not really enough to describe more advanced ideas like geometry.

Note that the word "space" is used in many different contexts in mathematics, often completely unrelated to each other or physical reality. For example topological spaces and linear spaces have completely different, unrelated definitions. Even though they do meet each other ultimately, e.g. as normed spaces.

Comment: Ah, ok. So what kind of structure should I read about to learn about how to distinguish between e.g. a line, or a surface (etc)? This is what I'm thinking of as "space", like, the space of a line, or the space of a plane (or a volume, etc). How to tell different spaces apart? I have some understanding of the Lebesgue covering dimension, and just the existence of that implies that different topological spaces can have different character at least akin to linear/planar/etc etc. Right?

Comment: @Andrew surface or line is a special case of manifold. But to understand manifolds you need to learn at least about linear spaces, metric spaces, normed spaces and differential calculus. Or what we call more generally: mathematical analysis.

Comment: Thank you. One last question, is it possible to clarify for me what kind of structure I mentioned in the original comment? 

({A},{B},{C},{D},{AB},{BC},{CD},{ABC},{BCD},{ABCD})

If this is not a topological space, or indeed a manifold, I am curious how to understand this kind of structure, which at least seems related to those concepts..

thanks again

Comment: @Andrew you may want to read about "partially ordered sets" or posets. It might be related. But to be honest: it doesn't really resemble anything that I know, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The data of a topological space consists of :

1. A set $X$.
2. A collection $T \subseteq P(X)$,
   subject to the following axioms :

Ax 1. $X$ and $\emptyset$ are members of $T$.

Ax 2. If $\{X_i : i \in I\}$ is an arbitrary collection of members of $T$ (that is, each $X_i$ should be an element of $T$), then $\cup_i X_i$ is a member of $T$.

Ax 3. If $U$ and $V$ are two members of $T$, then $U \cap V$ is a member of $T$.

In other words, $T$ should be closed under the empty set, X, arbitrary unions and **finite** intersections.

That's all. The pair $(X,T)$ is called a topological space and $T$ is called the topology of this space.

Answer (score 0):

For $\tau $ is a topology on set $X$ iff $\emptyset\in \tau, X\in \tau$, $\forall E_k \in \tau, N<\infty, \cap_{k=1}^N E_k \in \tau$, and $\forall N>0, \forall E_k\in \tau$, $\cup_{k=1}^N E_k\in \tau$.

That is, a topology is a subset of the Powerset that contains the set itself, the Empty set, arbitrary, possibly infinite, unions, and the intersection of any finite collection of sets in the topology.

You are right, if all possible singletons of a set are in the topology, then the topology is the Powerset. This isn't necessary though. Suppose $X=\{A,B,C,D\}$ only $\{A\}$ and $\{B\}$ are in $\tau$. Then adding $\{A,B\}$ suffices to form a topology on X. Then all 4 of the topology axioms are satisfied (assuming the whole set and empty set are already included).